# Removing the array element in mongoDB based on the position of element

Tags: arrays, mongodb, pull

Actually I need to remove an element from the array based on its position. Using $pop we can remove element from top or bottom (considering it as a stack. 0th element at top) as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945825/remove-element-from-array-in-mongodb).

We can also remove element from array based on the value of the elements in the array using $pull as explained [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24pull).

But I need to remove element from the array based on position. So is there any way I can do this.

Comment: That's not a particularly safe operation to do in a multitasking environment.  What if two threads try to remove element 4 at almost the same time?  Idempotent or atomic actions are generally what you want for all database operations.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From documentation:

```
{ $pull : { field : {$gt: 3} } } removes array elements greater than 3
```

So i suppose that you can do somethig like this for now:

```
{ $pull : { field : {$gt: 3, $lt: 5} } } // shoud remove elemet in 4 position
```

Or try update using [position operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-The%24positionaloperator), i suppose shoud be something like this:

```
  { $pull : "field.4" } 

  { $pull : {"field.$": 4}}
```

It is only a suggestion, because i can't test it right now.

**Update:**

Seems you cant do it right know in one step(there is such [bug in jira](http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1014))

But you can remove using unset element in position and that pull elemets with null value:

```
{$unset : {"array.4" : 1 }}
{$pull : {"array" : null}}
```

Comment: Doing that leads to an error: "Cannot update array.4 and array at the same time"

Answer (score 2):

That is how possible to do that with latest mongodb v4.2, ugly but working

````
     _id: ObjectId("5e4539cb6aebbeaa0a6b8fe7") 
   }, [
        { $set: 
          { notes: 
            { 
              $concatArrays: [
                { $slice: ['$notes', 4] }, 
                { $slice: ['$notes', { $add: [1, 4] }, { $size: '$notes' }]}
              ] 
            } 
          } 
        }
      ])```
````

Answer (score 0):

Here's your answer: [MongoDB pull array element from a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058748/mongodb-pull-array-element-from-a-collection#4059689)

To remove specific element from an array of some document first you need to identify this element. For instance I have a document with array and every element of this array is an object:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5140f34888dd50971900002d"),
    "_permissions" : {
        "edit" : [
            {
                "profile_id" : NumberLong(123),
                "comment" : "app/project owner"
            },
            {
                "profile_id" : NumberLong("153579099841888257"),
                "comment" : "project admin"
            },
            {
                "profile_id" : NumberLong("153579095869882369"),
                "comment" : "project admin"
            }
        ],
        "view" : [
            {
                "profile_id" : NumberLong(123),
                "comment" : "app/project owner"
            },
            {
                "profile_id" : NumberLong("153579099841888257"),
                "comment" : "project admin"
            },
            {
                "profile_id" : NumberLong("153579095869882369"),
                "comment" : "project admin"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

So let's remove `profile_id` with "153579099841888257" value from `_permissions.view` array.
Here we go

```
db.collection.update({_id: ObjectId("5140f34888dd50971900002d")}, {$pull:{"_permissions.view": {"profile_id": NumberLong("153579099841888257")}}});
```

1. I define scope of the object (to make sure id doesn't affect any other first found document)
2. Identify needed element to pull out: `profile_id` with "153579099841888257" value in the `_permissions.view` array