# Mongodb update() with $unset/$pull not doing $pull

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to remove some items from an array in a document in MongoDB:

```
doc1
  items
    item
       id=1
    item
       id=2
    item
       id=3
doc2
  items
    item
      id=4
    item
      id=5
    item
      id=6
```

I use this to remove for example item id=5:

```
(...)
updateItems({'items.id': 5},    { $unset: { 'items.$': 1 }},    { $pull: {'items'    : null} });
(...)
function updateItems(objmatch, objunset, objpull){  
coremodels.getProfileTable(req).update(
    objmatch, 
    objunset,
    {multi: true}, function(err) {
        coremodels.getProfileTable(req).update(
                        objmatch, 
                        objpull,
                        {multi: true}, function(err) {
        console.log('COMPLETED');
});
(...)
```

The $unset works fine, but the $pull doesn't seem to be working. The end result of this operation is an empty (Null) item 5.

Any ideas why the $pull is not removing the empty document?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Found this answer which suggests that what you're trying to do should work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4970050/893113

Comment: Thanks, yes I pretty much followed that as an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `updateArray` function takes two parameters, but you're passing it three. I don't think you're sending `{ $pull: {'items' : null} }` to the driver at all.

**Added:**

Once you nullify item 5, your match document no longer matches anything . The second time you cal update, try replacing `objmatch` with `{ }`, which should just remove any nulls.

Comment: Sorry I am, it was just a typo.

Comment: Of course! Well spotted! That was it, there was no id 5 by the time I tried $pull. THANK YOU!!!