# Move an array element from one array position to another (mongo)

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

I have a list like this:

```
{ 
    arr: [
        { _id: 'a', val: 1 }, 
        { _id: 'b', val: 4 }, 
        { _id: 'd', val: 0 }, 
        { _id: 'c', val: 8 }
    ] 
}
```

And I need to put the element `{_id: c}` before the element `{_id: d}`. How can I do it with mongo? Of course, I can download the doc to my server, prepare it and upload the one to the mongo server. But I think, it's not a good way.

**P.S: sorry, I need to move the element (push it to a new position and remove the one from old position)**

Comment: I think a easier way of doing that would be to make another id that you can more easily access, and sort by that id when you need to use the document.

Comment: Do you want to swap elements or to sort them?  If you need to sort them there is a $sort option you may be able to use.

Comment: Has anyone found the solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the keyword [`$position`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/position/#up._S_position) to specify where in the array you want to insert the value.  Use it when `$push`ing an element on and you'll be able to insert that element into a specific place in the array.

```
db.collection.update(
    {parameter: doc},
    {$push: {
        arr: {
            $each: [{_id: "c", val: 8}],
            $position: 2
        }
    })
```

This will push that object into position 2 of your array.  If you're looking to manipulate the array by removing objects at specific points, you can refer to the [answer I linked in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969768/removing-the-array-element-in-mongodb-based-on-the-position-of-element).

Comment: NIce, how does he remove the element in position 3? Maybe a working example would be good.

Comment: There are more ways to do that, using `$pull`.  I don't know if you can specify a `$position` field within `$pull`, but there are other answers for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969768/removing-the-array-element-in-mongodb-based-on-the-position-of-element

Comment: And what about the document which is at position 2

Comment: `$push` won't remove the document at position 3, and OP didn't ask to remove it, so this code preserves the array and just inserts.  But @Soren asked about removing the element at a certain position, so I included a link to do that with `$pull`

Comment: The author of this question specifically asked to shift the element from one position to another, not to push a new element. This is half  right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
db.myCollection.find().forEach(function(doc){
        db.myCollection.update({_id: doc._id},
          {$set: {"arr.2": doc.arr[3], "arr.3": doc.arr[2]}})
    })
OR
You can Pull and then push those documents
```

Comment: >> Of course, I can download the doc to my server, prepare it and upload the one to the mongo server. But I think, it's not a good way.

Comment: Does  the callback not copy this to the application rather than just work on the mongodb server?

Comment: @Soren yeap, but if I will work on the mongodb server I will block the main thread.

Comment: Not sure that is relevant, since the OP specifically wanted something that didn't copy the data across.