# Mongodb-Nodejs Pull Element From An Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Guys I want to `$pull` an element from array. Here:

**User's Follow:**

```
{ follow:
   [ 5edfe8f3bfc9d677005d55ca,
     5edfe92fbfc9d677005d55cc,
     5ee2326cc7351c5bb0b75f1a ],
```

**follow id:(Which we will pull)**

```
5edfe92fbfc9d677005d55cc
```

The process:

```
    .
    .
    
    User.update(user,{$pull: { follow: friend}}, function(err){
          if(err){
          console.log(err);
        }else{
          res.send("Success")
        } 
        });
    .
    .
```

Also I have tried with `$elemMatch`: [Mongodb Unfollow With $pull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62711831/mongodb-unfollow-with-pull/62722908#62722908)

Question: How to `$pull` specific element from an array?

But it doesnt work. Can someone help me to solve this problem ?

**Note:** Guys the id's are given as an example to understand well. The follow is the friends of current user. And if user wants to unfollow then it will `$pull` the friend(friend: the user on the profile page) Think like facebook's follow-unfollow request. So that if you want to answer please do not give example with id's above because follow id's always change user to user.

So how to pull specific element from an array?

Full Code:

```
app.post('/cikar/:id', function(req, res){

  User.find(req.user
  
  ).exec(function(err, user){
  
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
  }
    
    User.find({"username":req.params.id}, function(err, friend){
      
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
      }
    User.update(user,{$pull: { follow: friend}}, function(err){
      if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }else{
      res.send("Success")
    } 
    });
  });
  });
  });
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969768/removing-the-array-element-in-mongodb-based-on-the-position-of-element#:~:text=Here%27s%20your%20answer%20MongoDB%20pull%20array%20element%20from,every%20element%20of%20this%20array%20is%20an%20object%3A) may be what you need

Comment: I have eddited the question. In my project there is no certain ids because friends(follow) changes user to user

Comment: Can you show your schema please? Your query looks okay to me. Also, is `friend` an object or `friend's ID`?

Comment: friend is the user on the profile. Like owner of the profile

Comment: About schema: Follower is an object id

Comment: push query works fine but pull doesnt

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: Make sure the datatype matches.  The `$pull` is processed by the mongod not by mongoose, so there is no implicit type conversion.  `{$pull: "5edfe8f3bfc9d677005d55ca"}` will not do anything if the array contains `[ObjectId("5edfe8f3bfc9d677005d55ca")]`

Comment: But same codes with $push or $addToSet works fine

Comment: Can you provide some sample code that we can run to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I have added full code. Can you look at it please?

Comment: Does the follow array include the entire friend object? User.find will return a document, if follow only contains the _id, try `User.update(user,{$pull: { follow: friend._id}}`

Comment: I have tried that but it didnt work

Comment: Array show like this: 5edfe8f3bfc9d677005d55ca

Comment: Again it works when I do push or addtoset

Comment: hmm it says friend._id is undefined but

Comment: It shows friend but when I want to take just _id it says undefined