# Query for documents where array size is greater than 1

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB collection with documents in the following format:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4e8ae86d08101908e1000001"),
  "name" : ["Name"],
  "zipcode" : ["2223"]
}
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4e8ae86d08101908e1000002"),
  "name" : ["Another ", "Name"],
  "zipcode" : ["2224"]
}
```

I can currently get documents that match a specific array size:

```
db.accommodations.find({ name : { $size : 2 }})
```

This correctly returns the documents with 2 elements in the `name` array. However, I can't do a `$gt` command to return all documents where the `name` field has an array size of greater than 2:

```
db.accommodations.find({ name : { $size: { $gt : 1 } }})
```

How can I select all documents with a `name` array of a size greater than one (preferably without having to modify the current data structure)?

Comment: The newer versions of MongoDB have the $size operator; you should check out @tobia's answer

Comment: Actual solution:
FooArray:{$gt:{$size:'length'}} 
--> lenght can be any number

Comment: @SergiNadal: I don't think this `FooArray:{$gt:{$size:'length'}}` is working! Well at least on nested object which is an array `person:{ids:[123,456]}`

Comment: Arrays should have a plural name so your array field `name` should be named `names`.

Answer (score 623, accepted):

**Update:**

*For mongodb versions **2.2+** more efficient way to do this described by **@JohnnyHK** in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15224544/508601).*

---

1. Using [$where](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#op._S_where)

   db.accommodations.find( { $where: "this.name.length > 1" } );

But...

> Javascript executes more slowly than the native operators listed on
> this page, but is very flexible. See the server-side processing page
> for more information.

2. Create **extra** field `NamesArrayLength`, update it with names array length and then use in queries:

   db.accommodations.find({"NamesArrayLength": {$gt: 1} });

It will be better solution, and will work much faster (you can create index on it).

Comment: Great, that was perfect thank you. Although I actually have some documents that don't have a name so had to modify the query to be:  db.accommodations.find( { $where: "if (this.name && this.name.length > 1) {return this; } "} );

Comment: you are welcome, yes you can use any javascript in `$where`, it is very flexible.

Comment: @emson I would think it would be quicker to do something like { "name": {$exists:1}, $where: "this.name.lenght > 1"}  ... minimizing the part in the slower javascript query.  I assume that works and that the $exists would have higher precedence.

Comment: I had no idea you could embed javascript in the query, json can be cumbersome. Many of these queries are one time only entered by hand so optimization is not required. I'll use this trick often +1

Comment: for the second answer, how to update the array length when I need to remove multiple elements?

Comment: More efficient than `db.accommodations.find( { $where: "this.name && this.name.length > 1" } )`?

Comment: After adding/removing elements from the Array, we need to update the count of "NamesArrayLength".
Can this done in a single query? Or it requires 2 queries, one for updating the array and another for updating the count?

Answer (score 1787):

There's a more efficient way to do this in MongoDB 2.2+ now that you can use numeric array indexes (0 based) in query object keys.

```
// Find all docs that have at least two name array elements.
db.accommodations.find({'name.1': {$exists: true}})
```

You can support this query with an index that uses a partial filter expression (requires 3.2+):

```
// index for at least two name array elements
db.accommodations.createIndex(
    {'name.1': 1},
    {partialFilterExpression: {'name.1': {$exists: true}}}
);
```

Comment: Could somebody please explain how to index this.

Comment: I'm really impressed with how effective this is and also how 'out of the box' you were thinking to find this solution.  This works on 2.6, as well.

Comment: Works on 3.0 aswell. Thank you so much for finding this.

Comment: What if `name` has space, like `"Name Field"`?

Comment: @Dims No difference, really: `{'Name Field.1': {$exists: true}}`.

Comment: @JohnnyHK , how can check for less than with this? ie name filed has less than 2 array elements?

Comment: Can't imagine how to use this when index depends on some value stored in document.

Comment: again it checks a fixed value ( > 1). the question is : "How to query for documents where array size is greater than one". What if array lenghts are variable?

Comment: It'd be helpful to mention in the answer that indexation is 0-based here.

Comment: This isn't a good answer, because `x.1` can exist while `x.0` is undefined.

Comment: Can someone please explain why MongoDB still does not allow querying for a size range?  It boggles my mind.

Comment: I would go for `db.accommodations.find({'name.0': {$exists: true}})` instead as the the first index of an array in mongodb is 0. Is there a reason why you went for 1 ?

Comment: @JubaFourali The question is regarding _greater_ than 1 element.

Answer (score 180):

I believe this is the fastest query that answers your question, because it doesn't use an interpreted `$where` clause -- it uses the [`$size` array operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/size/) and the [`$exists` element operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) combined with [`$nor` logical operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/nor/)

```
{$nor: [
    {name: {$exists: false}},
    {name: {$size: 0}},
    {name: {$size: 1}}
]}
```

It means "all documents except those without a name (either non existant or empty array) or with just one name."

Test:

```
> db.test.save({})
> db.test.save({name: []})
> db.test.save({name: ['George']})
> db.test.save({name: ['George', 'Raymond']})
> db.test.save({name: ['George', 'Raymond', 'Richard']})
> db.test.save({name: ['George', 'Raymond', 'Richard', 'Martin']})
> db.test.find({$nor: [{name: {$exists: false}}, {name: {$size: 0}}, {name: {$size: 1}}]})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("511907e3fb13145a3d2e225b"), "name" : [ "George", "Raymond" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("511907e3fb13145a3d2e225c"), "name" : [ "George", "Raymond", "Richard" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("511907e3fb13145a3d2e225d"), "name" : [ "George", "Raymond", "Richard", "Martin" ] }
>
```

Comment: @viren I don't know. This was certainly better than Javascript solutions, but for newer MongoDB you should probably use `{'name.1': {$exists: true}}`

Comment: @Tobia my first use was $exists only but it actually use whole table scan so very slow.
    db.test.find({"name":"abc","d.5":{$exists:true},"d.6":{$exists:true}})    
 "nReturned" : 46525,
 "executionTimeMillis" : 167289,
 "totalKeysExamined" : 10990840,
 "totalDocsExamined" : 10990840,

 "inputStage" : {
  "stage" : "IXSCAN",
  "keyPattern" : {
   "name" : 1,
   "d" : 1
  },
  "indexName" : "name_1_d_1",
  "direction" : "forward",
  "indexBounds" : {
   "name" : [
     "[\"abc\", \"abc\"]"
   ],
   "d" : [
     "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
   ]
  }
 } If you see it scanned whole table.

Comment: Would be nice to update the answer to recommend other alternatives (like `'name.1': {$exists: true}}`, and also because this is hardcoded for "1" and doesn't scale to an arbitrary or parametric minimum array length.

Comment: This may be fast but falls apart if you're looking for lists > N, where N isn't small.

Comment: This doesn't work if you're looking for a nested array where the inside array has length of at least 2, but {'foo.bar.details.2': {$exists: true}} will find those.

Answer (score 95):

You can use aggregate, too:

```
db.accommodations.aggregate(
[
     {$project: {_id:1, name:1, zipcode:1, 
                 size_of_name: {$size: "$name"}
                }
     },
     {$match: {"size_of_name": {$gt: 1}}}
])
```

// you add "size_of_name" to transit document and use it to filter the size of the name

Comment: This solution is the most general, along with @JohnnyHK's since it can be used for any array size.

Comment: if i want to use "size_of_name" inside projection then how can i do that ?? Actually i want to use $slice inside projection where its value is equal to $slice : [0, "size_of_name" - skip] ??

Answer (score 92):

You can use [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) ( 3.6 mongo version operator ) to use aggregation functions in regular query.

Compare [`query operators`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/) vs [`aggregation comparison operators`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-comparison/).

```
db.accommodations.find({$expr:{$gt:[{$size:"$name"}, 1]}})
```

Comment: How would you pass instead of `$name` an array that is a subdocument, for example in a "person" record, `passport.stamps`? I tried various quoting combinations but I get `"The argument to $size must be an array, but was of type: string/missing"`.

Comment: @DanDascalescu It looks like stamps is not present in all documents. You can use [ifNull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) to output empty array when the stamps is not present. Something like `db.col.find({$expr:{$gt:[{$size:{$ifNull:["$passport.stamps", []]}}, 1]}})`

Comment: Thanks, I was looking to size an array key and this works perfectly!

**db.getCollection("companies").find({ $expr: {$gt: [{$size:"$keywords"}, 0]} })**


    Also, you may change $gt to $eq to query those docs with no data to size:
**db.getCollection("companies").find({ $expr: {$eq: [{$size:"$keywords"}, 0]} })**

Answer (score 63):

Try to do something like this:

```
db.getCollection('collectionName').find({'ArrayName.1': {$exists: true}})
```

1 is number, if you want to fetch record greater than 50 then do ArrayName.50
Thanks.

Comment: The same answer was given [three years earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/15224544/1).

Comment: can we put some dynamic number like "ArrayName.<some_num>" inside the query?

Comment: Yes you can use any number. If you want to fetch record greater than N then pass n.

Answer (score 54):

MongoDB 3.6 include $expr
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/

You can use $expr in order to evaluate an expression inside a $match, or find.

```
{ $match: {
           $expr: {$gt: [{$size: "$yourArrayField"}, 0]}
         }
}
```

or find

```
collection.find({$expr: {$gte: [{$size: "$yourArrayField"}, 0]}});
```

Comment: While correct, this is a duplicate answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48410837/2424641 by @user2683814

Answer (score 47):

None of the above worked for me. This one did so I'm sharing it:

```
db.collection.find( {arrayName : {$exists:true}, $where:'this.arrayName.length>1'} )
```

Comment: javascript executes more slowly than the native operators provided by mongodb, but it's very flexible. see:http://stackoverflow.com/a/7811259/2893073, So the final solution is : http://stackoverflow.com/a/15224544/2893073

Answer (score 43):

Although the above answers all work, What you originally tried to do was the correct way, however you just have the syntax backwards (switch "$size" and "$gt")..

Correct:

```
db.collection.find({items: {$gt: {$size: 1}}})
```

Comment: I don't see why so many downvotes - this works perfectly for me!

Comment: Works perfectly fine, v 4.2.5

Comment: always post version when posting solutions like that. not working on 4.2

Comment: As of 4.4, the "correct" is not working. Just because `$gt` parameter must be a number. Either `$size` parameter must be a number.

Comment: Works fine on "4.4.8"

Comment: works fine on 5.0.6

Comment: The people saying this doesn't work must have pasted the part that clearly says incorrect

Comment: This should definitely be the accepted answer. This answer is more generalizable than other "hacky" answers and is faster than any answers base on "where", and simpler than any answer based on aggregate.

Comment: It does not work for me. I have 300K records, they all have either 1 or 2 entries. If I do `{items: {$gt: {$size: 2}}}` I get back all 300K and it should be empty list. (assumming `items` is the array) ver 5.0.15

Comment: Mysteriously it only works for me with ```$gt```, but not with ```$lt``` which is what I need ..

Comment: For me, on Mongo 6, this format always returns all documents (even those that shouldn't match) if all documents have the array field, and always returns no documents if at least some of the documents do not have the array field.

Answer (score 28):

```
db.accommodations.find({"name":{"$exists":true, "$ne":[], "$not":{"$size":1}}})
```

Comment: This doesn't scale well to other minimum sizes (say, 10).

Comment: same as first answer

Answer (score 15):

I found this solution, to find items with an array field greater than certain length

```
db.allusers.aggregate([
    { $match: { username: { $exists: true } } },
    { $project: { count: { $size: "$locations.lat" } } },
    { $match: { count: { $gt: 20 } } },
]);
```

The first $match aggregate uses an argument that's true for all the documents.  Without it, I would get an error exception

```
"errmsg" : "exception: The argument to $size must be an Array, but was of type: EOO"
```

Comment: This is essentially the same answer as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32429310/1269037), provided 2 years earlier.

Answer (score 12):

You can MongoDB aggregation to do the task:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      arrayLength: {$size: '$array'}
    },
  },
  {
    $match: {
      arrayLength: {$gt: 1}
    },
  },
])
```

Answer (score 5):

this will work for you

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $gt: [{ $size: "$arrayField" }, 1]
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work in Compass also. This is the fastest of all i have tried without indexing.

```
 {$expr: {
            $gt: [
              {
                $size: { "$ifNull": [ "$name", [] ] }
              },
              1
            ]
          }}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use $expr to cover this

```js
// $expr: Allows the use of aggregation expressions within the query language.
// syntax: {$expr: {<expression>}}

db.getCollection("person_service").find(
    { 
        "$expr" : { 
            // services is Array, find services length gt 3
            "$gt" : [
                { 
                    "$size" : "$services"
                }, 
                3.0
            ]
        }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
{ $where: function() { return this.name && this.name.length > 2;}}
```

The trick was the check for if the value existed first before checking for the length.

I kept getting an error:

> Executor error during find command :: caused by :: **TypeError: this.name is undefined** : @:1:15

That's because not all the documents had a name field (or whatever field you call it, replace `name` with the array you are interested in, e.g *scores*).

Unfortunately the error was very vague and I tried a whole bunch of other things before realising this was the issue.

Note: I'm using MongoDB (Atlas) v6.0.10

Comment: Ohh, I just realised mine is basically like https://stackoverflow.com/a/23644055/1495634 but with a single $where, but the answer by @lesolorzanov is probably more performant if you have an index and it's a concern for you.
But this one is probably easier to remember. Depends on your use case.