# count the array's length and get newly added elements in mongodb+php

Tags: php, mongodb

Hi there I am having a MongoDB document in users collection:

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("51d9534fc469880b338903eb"),
   "inbox": {
      "0": {},
      "1": {} ,
      "2": {} 
           ...
    },

}
```

According to requirement i need to check inbox every  5 minutes. So I am looking for:

1. To find the length of inbox.
2. Imagine my inbox lenght is 4 but 2 new messages came in, how would i get only those new messages.

After a bit of research i found that i can check if there are any new messages in my inbox  using `db.collection.find({ tags : { $size: 4 }});` ,  but now my question is how do i find those newly added messages. It would be really great if you can suggest a better way to get around this situation.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`$slice`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/slice/#proj._S_slice) operator to skip some items in your array:

```
db.collection.find({ tags : { $size : 4 } }, { inbox : { $slice : -4 } })
```

Check if your `inbox` field is really an array, because on your example it's a document.

Perhaps you should modified the query too, assuming the you have the length of your inbox, fetch for new messages will be:

```
var len = current_length; // comes from your app
var field = 'inbox.' + len;
// the query will check if the index "len" of inbox array exists
db.collection.find({ field : { $exists: true }, { inbox : { $slice : -len } }}
```

Check this question for more information about index querying: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15224544/1877296

Answer (score 0):

First off, the best way to design the schema is to not use an object for `inbox`; you should be using an array.

Second, however, do you know what are new messages (i.e. 2 out of 4 messages are new)? I am going out on a limb stating that there is a `read` field which will be either `true` or `false`.

So what you are actually, most likely, asking is how to get all messages, sorted by send date, where `read` is `false`; alternatively you can also use a `MongoDate` ( http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodate.php ) `lastPullTime` to keep track of it storign the value in the `$_SESSION`.

In this example we are going for the `read` field. I will also assume you have a sent date in `ISODate()` format called `sent`.

For this we can use the aggregation framework like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Let's get our user
    {$match:{_id:ObjectId()}},

    // Now we want to unwind the inbox so we can operate on it
    {$unwind:'$inbox'},

    // Now we want only messages that are not read
    {$match: {'inbox.read':false}},

    // Now lets do our sort by newest
    {$sort: {'inbox.sent':-1}},

    // Now lets group them back up
    {$group: {_id:'$_id', inbox: {$addToSet:'$inbox'}}}
])
```

Or you can do it in PHP with [asort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) on `$doc['inbox']`