# $unwind, remove elements with empty arrays

Tags: mongodb

I want to aggregate a document by unwinding a subdocument array and filter the results which has no element in the array. Is there a way to find the elements with 0 length subdocument array and exclude them in the aggregation?

Comment: What defines an empty suboducment, also is it the field in the docuemnt you wanna make sure is empty or a field in the subdocument?

Comment: On the parent document, there is a field which is a subdocument array. I'm unwinding on that array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided this is a field in the root document and not the subdocument you wish to check is empty or not you can do:

```
{$match:{'$subdocument':{$gt:{}}}},
{$unwind:'$subdocument'}
```

For reference, another method is stated here: [Query for documents where array size is greater than 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811163/in-mongo-db-how-do-i-find-documents-where-array-size-is-greater-than-1/15224544#15224544) by @JohnnyHK