# Mongoid embeded document query count in range

Tags: mongoid

Trying to work out how to do a mongoid query to return Documents with a range of embeded documents
e.g.

```
class Question
  embeds_many :question_response,
```

get questions that have only 1,2 or 3 responses

```
Question.between(:question_response.count, 1, 3)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In MongoDB, how do I find documents where array size is greater than 1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811163/in-mongodb-how-do-i-find-documents-where-array-size-is-greater-than-1)

Comment: that question is about size of an array, I am looking to count the number of embedded objects

Comment: But looking for things with 1, 2, or 3 responses *is* about the size of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who wanted to know.

with_size worked.

Thanks