# Finding records where arrays contain more than X records?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection that contains documents that are structured like this:

```
{
   "title": "some title",
   "participants": [1,2,3],
   "questions": ["question1", "question2", "question3"]
}
```

I would like to write a query that will allow me to select all documents that have more than 4 elements in the `participants` array **and** more than 3 elements in the `questions` array.  I was able to run the following query:

```
db.myCollection.find({
        "$where": "this.questions.length > 3", 
        "$where": "this.participants.length > 4"}
).pretty()
```

But it is only applying the last `$where` condition (so documents where there is only 1 question are still being returned).  How can I apply multiple conditionals based on array length to my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the dot notation to check if a specific index exists like:

```
db.myCollection.find({
        "questions.3" : {$exists : true}, 
        "participants.4" : {$exists : true}}
)
```

which is equivalent to "find documents where questions.size() > 3and participants.size() > 4".

This approach was suggested by [JohnyHK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1259510/johnnyhk) [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811163/in-mongodb-how-do-i-find-documents-where-array-size-is-greater-than-1) (second answer)