# How to query as the count of hitting element in a list on a field which is a list in Mongodb using Python?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Given the following documents in the **ariticle** collection:

```
{ _id: 1, words: [ "Apple", "IT", "Company", "IOS" ] }

{ _id: 2, words: [ "Google", "Android", "Search Engine","Company" ] }
```

Now, I wanna to query on the *words* field to get the documents that hit a specified number of elements in the list *["Company","Apple","IT","Google","Iphone","Smartisan"]*. For example, I wanna to get the documents that hits any of 3 in the list above on field *words*.

How to write the query statements in pymongo, or does pymongo support query like this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`$size`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/size/) operator to select arrays of a certain size.

```
db.article.find({ "words" : { "$size" : 3 } })
```

Obviously, replace `db` and `article` with the variables identifying your database and collection.

See also this related question:

[Query for documents where array size is greater than 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811163/in-mongodb-how-do-i-find-documents-where-array-size-is-greater-than-1)