# How to check if a field in MongoDB is [] or {}?

Tags: mongodb, database

MongoDB. One of the fields of a document can be either an array, including an empty array, a subdocument, that can be empty or not, or null, or not exist at all. I need a condition for find() that will match a non-empty subdocument, and only that.

So:

```
fieldName: {} - no match.
fieldName: [ { id:0 } ] - no match.
fieldName: [ {} ] - no match.
No field called fieldName - no match.
fieldName: null - no match.
fieldName: { id: 0 } - match.
```

I have no rights to modify anything, I have to work with the database as is. How to formulate that find() ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In MongoDB, how do I find documents where array size is greater than 1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811163/in-mongodb-how-do-i-find-documents-where-array-size-is-greater-than-1)

Comment: Can you describe it a bit more clearly? Do I get it right that there is a semantic difference wether the same key holds an array or a subdocument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following query:

```
db.test.find({ 
   "fieldName": { "$gt": {} }, 
   "fieldName.0": { "$exists": false } 
})
```

For example, with the above test case, insert the following documents:

```
db.test.insert([
    { _id: 1, fieldName: {} },
    { _id: 2, fieldName: [ { id: 0 } ] },
    { _id: 3, fieldName: [ {} ] },
    { _id: 4 },
    { _id: 5, fieldName: null},
    { _id: 6, fieldName: { id: 0 } }
])
```

the above query will return the document with `_id: 6`

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : 6,
    "fieldName" : {
        "id" : 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [**`$type`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) and the [**`$exists`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/)  operator.

The first check the type of `id` and the latter if `fieldname` is an array using the so called [*dot notation*](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation).

```
db.collection.find({ 
    "fieldName.id": { $type: 1 }, "fieldName.0": { $exists: false }
})
```