# how to count number of sub object (same document) in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Example document:

```
{
    "aliases" : {
        "name" : [ 
            "Brinton McKay", 
            "Dr. Theopolis", 
            "Galactic Spiral Sound", 
            "Highrise", 
            "Memory Boy", 
            "Semblance Factor", 
            "Spy (2)", 
            "Three O'Clock High"]}
}
```

How i can count the number of "name" under  "aliases"? 
I would like to print all _id who which contains more than 3 aliases. 
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15224544/3264192).

Comment: So in this case it would be: `db.coll.find({'aliases.name.3': {$exists: true}})`

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below query :

```
db.collection.find({ $where : function() 
{ return Object.keys(this.aliases.name).length > 3 } });
```

OR

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$project : { _id :1 , numb : {$size : "$aliases.name"} }
},
{$match : { numb :{$gt : 3 }}
}
]);
```

PS : you can see the documentation in below link : 
    http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/

Comment: This is the error:
error: {
 "$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue $size needs a number",
 "code" : 17287
}

Comment: can you check the above query ?

Comment: It works but as { $size: 3 }   not as  {$size:{$gt:3}} , how i can use $gt? 

Thanks very much

Comment: I have posted anothet query using aggregate function, can you check that as well. I have edited that in my post. please try them.

Comment: This one is perfect: db.coll.find({'aliases.name.3': {$exists: true}})
Great  JohnnyHK & also Yathish. You guys are good.