# Mongoose find all documents where array.length is greater than 0 & sort the data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am using mongoose to perform CRUD operation on MongoDB. This is how my schema looks.

```
var EmployeeSchema = new Schema({
      name: String,
      description: {
        type: String,
        default: 'No description'
      },
      departments: []

    });
```

Each employee can belong to multiple department. Departments array will look like [1,2,3]. In this case departments.length = 3. If the employee does not belong to any department, the departments.length will be equal to 0.

I need to find all employee where EmployeeSchema.departments.length > 0 & if query return more than 10 records, I need to get only employees having maximum no of departments.

Is it possible to use Mongoose.find() to get the desired result?

Comment: similar to this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811163/how-to-query-for-documents-where-array-size-is-greater-than-one-1-in-mongodb

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Presuming your model is called `Employee`:

```
Employee.find({ "departments.0": { "$exists": true } },function(err,docs) {

})
```

As [**`$exists`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) asks for the `0` index of an array which means it has something in it.

The same applies to a maximum number:

```
Employee.find({ "departments.9": { "$exists": true } },function(err,docs) {

})
```

So that needs to have at least 10 entries in the array to match.

Really though you should record the length of the array and update with **`$inc`** every time something is added. Then you can do:

```
Employee.find({ "departmentsLength": { "$gt": 0 } },function(err,docs) {

})
```

On the "departmentsLength" property you store. That property can be indexed, which makes it much more efficient.

Comment: Strange, but first example doesn't works for me. May be this is old solution that not works with new versions or something?

Comment: this is an old solution try the answer of https://stackoverflow.com/a/51260864/10251064

Answer (score 22):

By some reason, selected answer doesn't work as for now. There is the **$size** [operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/size/).

Usage:

```
collection.find({ field: { $size: 1 } });
```

Will look for arrays with length 1.

Comment: Note that this finds *only* documents where field has exactly one element.

Comment: The question says "greater than 0", it doesn't mean the size must be exactly 1.

Comment: I went to the mongodb docs to find an edit for this (hoping I could use a $gt or something) but apparently the $size never accepts a range. I hope they change this in the future.

Answer (score 1):

use can using [$where](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/index.html) like this:

```
await EmployeeSchema.find( {$where:'this.departments.length>0'} )
```

Answer (score 0):

### Efficient Method to Retrieve Array Length in Mongoose with Virtual Fields

I recently encountered a challenge when attempting to retrieve the length of an array using Mongoose virtual fields and pre-hooks. Despite the array (this.users) being correctly populated and visible in the console or debugger, a direct attempt to access this.users.length resulted in a "Cannot read properties of undefined" error.

After exploring various options, I found a simple and effective solution using a ternary check:

```
return this.departments ? this.departments.length : null;
```

This ternary check ensures that the array exists before attempting to access its length, preventing the error. This approach proved to be a practical way to obtain the count of users without resorting to additional database queries.

```
EmployeeSchema.virtual('departmentsCount').get(function() {
    return this.departments ? this.departments.length : null;
});
```

Answer (score -3):

If anyone is looking for array length is greater than 1, you can do like below,

```
db.collection.find({ "arrayField.1" : { $exists: true }})
```

The above query will check if the array field has value at the first index, it means it has more than 1 items in the array. Note: Array index start from 0.

Comment: $size needs a number