# mongoose find() documents having a property array of size > 0

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a Client schema that contains one of the properties: services, which is an array.

**Client.Schema**

```
const clientSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  compName: { type: String, required: true },
  ....
  ....
  services: [{
    servName: String,
    servCat: String,
    freq: String,
    fees: Number,
    dueDay: Number,
    dueMonth: Number,
  }]
});
```

I need to write a query which will return all the clients that have at least one service in the services array. I tried the below query but it gives me an error  `The expression evaluated to a falsy value:↵↵  assert.ok(!isNaN(val))`

**mongoose Query**

```
const clients = await Client.find({ 'services': { $size: { $gt: 0} } }).lean().sort('compName');
```

what would be the correct mongoose query for this?
pls help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoose find all documents where array.length is greater than 0 & sort the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31677061/mongoose-find-all-documents-where-array-length-is-greater-than-0-sort-the-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the documents where exists value 0 (i.e. exists at lest one document) in this way:

```
db.collection.find({
  "services.0": {
    "$exists": true
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DWvo0WXVnot)

Another option is to use [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) which, as said into documentations:

> Allows the use of aggregation expressions within the query language.

So you can do this query

```
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$gte": [{$size: "$services"},1]
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pKoPeIfQoCa)

Using mongoose is the same query:

```js
var find = await yourModel.find({"$expr": {
    "$gte": [{$size: "$services"},1]
  }}).lean().sort('compName');
```

or

```js
var find = await yourModel.find({"services.0": {
    "$exists": true
  }}).lean().sort('compName');
```