# query to Find keys having more than one values in the list Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have data in MongoDB like the below

```
test{ 
[{"key":"469","values":["BALTIMORE","BALTIMORE CITY"]}],
[{"key":"503","values":["BALTIMORE"]}],
[{"key":"505","values":["FAIRFAX"]}],
[{"key":"517","values":["COLUMBIA","BELAIR","BELAIR"]}],
[{"key":"534","values":["BETHEL","BETHEL"]}],
[{"key":"471","values":["HAGGERS","HAGGERS"]}],
[{"key":"587","values":["SAN FRANCISCO","SAN FRANCISCO"]}],
[{"key":"551","values":["DALLAS"]}]};
```

i would like to get the keys having more than one values.
like

```
[{"key":"469","values":["BALTIMORE","BALTIMORE CITY"]}],
[{"key":"517","values":["COLUMBIA","BELAIR","BELAIR"]}],
[{"key":"534","values":["BETHEL","BETHEL"]}],
[{"key":"471","values":["HAGGERS","HAGGERS"]}],
[{"key":"587","values":["SAN FRANCISCO","SAN FRANCISCO"]}],
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query for documents where array size is greater than 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811163/query-for-documents-where-array-size-is-greater-than-1)

Comment: Thanks, That works fine.

Comment: This is the solution to use: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15224544/