# Laravel-MongoDB query find all documents where field(array) has at least one element

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, laravel-5.4, jenssegers-mongodb

I am using Laravel-MongoDB query builder. A document of my collection(words) is below:

```
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("58464564545yb45y45yf"),
    "word" : "Bird",
    "keys" : [ {"title": "t1"}, {"title": "t2"} ]
}
```

How do I find all documents where the field "keys" size is greater than 0 ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811163/query-for-documents-where-array-size-is-greater-than-1

Comment: Thanks Shaishab, I know how to do it in mongo. I asked to find out, how to do it using jenssegers' package Laravel-MongoDB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a few searching and according to the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42195574/2193751

I found this

```
$ords = Word::where('keys.0', 'exists', true)->get();
```

It works for me.