# How to query embedded array by key name in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have documents that look like this (for example purposes).

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("591675e89a89201e4d520c89"),
    "raw_data_history" : {
        "APR-2017" : [ 
            {
                "count" : "540421",
                "reason" : "blah blah",
            },
            {
                "count" : "111111",
                "reason" : "blah blah 2",
            }
        ],
 "MAY-2017" : [ 
            {
                "count" : "13",
                "reason" : "blah blah",
            },
            {
                "count" : "100",
                "reason" : "blah blah 2",
            }
        ],
    },
    "review" : false,
    "active" : true,

}
```

I want to get all the documents in the collection where APR-2017 has more than 1 array element contents. I have tried the following:

```
db.getCollection('collections').find( {raw_data_history.APR-2017 : {$exists:true}, $where:'this.raw_data_history.APR-2017.length>1'} )
```

but I get

```
Error: Line 1: Unexpected token .
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query for documents where array size is greater than 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811163/query-for-documents-where-array-size-is-greater-than-1)

Answer (score 1):

Use to `$size` operator in aggregation. If you want to do it without aggregating, you'll need to have a field to store the size of your array. [$size documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/)

`db.collections.aggregate(
   {$project : {numberOfElements : {$size : "$raw_data_history.APR-2017"}, doc : "$$ROOT"}},
   {$match : {numberOfElements : {$gt : 1}}}
)`

Edit : A little clarification:

- $project stage will project the size of your array, along with the full document. It's practically like adding a field to keep track of the array size to your document.
- $match stage simply filters the document, so that it'll only return you document with more than 1 array in APR-2017

Answer (score 1):

When you want to use field inside object, you have to pass that field name in quotes("").

below query work for your requirement.

db.getCollection('collections').find( {"raw_data_history.APR-2017.1" : {$exists:true}} )

put raw_data_history.APR-2017.1 in double quotes.