# MongoTemplate Query to find Objects with child array size greater than

Tags: java, spring-data, mongotemplate

I need to write a Query which can find objects in DB whose child array size is greater than something.

My Object looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("sbg8732god78"),
    "studentIds" : [ "d3782gdo", "d8o3g7" ]
    ...
}
```

I need to find all objects with `studentIds` array size greater than `n`. I was looking at available methods like:

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("studentIds").exists(true));
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("studentIds").size().gt(0));
```

But `size()` method accepts an integer. How can this be done?

Answer (score 6):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811163/query-for-documents-where-array-size-is-greater-than-1/15224544#15224544), you can query for the existence of indices. This allows you to make the equivalent of a `>=` expression. Examples:

```java
// find where studentIds.size() >= 1
mongoTemplate.find(Query.query(Criteria.where("studentIds.0").exists(true);

// find where studentIds.size() >= 50
mongoTemplate.find(Query.query(Criteria.where("studentIds.49").exists(true);
```