# Mongo DB aggregation array size greater than match

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection where investments is an array inside the mongodb document. Now using aggregation I am trying to filter results where investments length is more than 5 times and then do the next processing using match query.

```
 Collection{
 _id:000000
 --------------------- 
 "investments" : [      {
          hhhhhhhhhhhhhh 
         },
         {
           hhhhhhhhhhhhhh 
          } }]
-----------------
```

The match query I wrote like below which isn't working. Any suggestions:

```
db.companies.aggregate( [
    { $match:  {"founded_year" : 2004}, 
  {  "investments" : {$size: : { $gte: 5 } } }  },
----------------------------------
--------------------------------
]}
```

Comment: See if this [helps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7811163)

Comment: You can use `db.companies.find({"$expr":{"$and":[{"$eq":["$founded_year", 2004]}, {"$gte":[{"$size":"$investments"}, 5]}]}})` in 3.6

Answer (score 45):

#### With `aggregate`:

```
db.companies.aggregate([
  { $match:  { "founded_year":2004 } },
  { $project: { founded_year:1,  
                moreThanFive: { $gt: [ {$size: "$external_links" }, 5 ] } } },
  { $match: { moreThanFive : true }} ,
])
```

You will need to:
1. Include a `$project` stage, to find the number of investement (the `size` of the array), and check if that greater than 5.
2. and then do another `$match` stage to filter those with `moreThanFive` equals to `true`.

#### With `find`:

```
db.companies.find({'investments.5': {$exists: true}})
```

You ask if the position number 6 in the `investments` array exists.

Comment: It looks like your second option (with `find`) is also working for a $match in an aggregation. Since it looks like dereferencing, I suppose it is pretty fast. Would you still recommend the first method for an aggregation?