# How to find array greater than document size in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have schema like below

```
[
{
 id:"111"
 tags:[222,333,444,555]
},
{
 id: "222"
 tags:[312,345,534]
},
{
 id:"333"
 tags:[111,222,333,444,555]
},

]
```

I want to find all documents where tags array size is greater than document size returned by `$match` in aggregation pipeline, so in above Ex. the number of documents are 3 so i want to return all documents having tags array size greater that 3

```
[
{
 id:"111"
 tags:[222,333,444,555]
},
{
 id:"333"
 tags:[111,222,333,444,555]
},

]
```

I am using aggregation pipeline to process other info, I am stuck at how to have store document size so that i can find all tags greater than document size

below is query which i am using, i want to do it in aggregation and in one call

```
.aggregate([
        
   {
      "$match":{
         "ids":{
            "$in":[
               "111",
               "222",
                "333"
            ]
         }
      }
   })]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongo DB aggregation array size greater than match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48847800/mongo-db-aggregation-array-size-greater-than-match)

Comment: no it does not as there is static size, in my case the size of array depends on document size returned by "match"  in aggregate

Comment: Do you mean collection size (document count), as in the number of documents in a collections?

Comment: yes, the number of documents returned by $match in aggregation pipeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try,

- `$match` you condition
- `$group` by null and make `root` array of documents and get count of root documents in `count`
- `$unwind` deconstruct `root` array
- `$match` `tags` size and `count` greater than or not using `$expr` expression match
- `$replaceRoot` to replace `root` object in root

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { id: { $in: ["111", "222", "333"] } } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      root: { $push: "$$ROOT" },
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$root" },
  { $match: { $expr: { $gt: [{ $size: "$root.tags" }, "$count"] } } },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$root" } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LCt1ltfotzq)

---

Second option:

- first 2 stages `$match` and `$group` both are same as like above query,
- `$project` to filter root array match condition if `tags` size and `count` greater than or not, this will return filtered root array
- `$unwind` deconstruct root array
- `$replaceRoot` replace root object to root

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { id: { $in: ["111", "222", "333"] } } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      root: { $push: "$$ROOT" },
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      root: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$root",
          cond: { $gt: [{ $size: "$$this.tags" }, "$count"] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$root" },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$root" } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TGbw55khmdI)

> You can skip `$unwind` and `$replaceRoot` stages if you want because this query always return one document in root, so you can easily access like this `result[0]['root']`, you can save 2 stages processing and execution time.

Answer (score 3):

Facet helps you to solve this problem.

- `$facet` helps to categorize the incoming documents. We use `totalDoc` for counting the document and `allDocuments` for getting all the documents
- `$arrayElemAt` helps to get the first object from `totalDoc` where we already know that only one object should be inside the `totalDoc`. Because when we group it, we use `_id:null`
- `$unwind` helps to de-structure the `allDocuments` array

Here is the code

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      totalDoc: [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: null,
            count: {
              $sum: 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      allDocuments: [
        {
          $project: {
            tags: 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      totalDoc: {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          "$totalDoc",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$allDocuments"
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      sizeGtDoc: {
        $gt: [
          {
            $size: "$allDocuments.tags"
          },
          "$totalDoc.count"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      sizeGtDoc: true
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$allDocuments"
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/at--WHrvdbK)**

Comment: This seems to work,but query is too large for small task, i will accept this answer if i don't get any shorter answer

Comment: Ok, no issues. I'm also checking to short this one

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`$facet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) to get two streams i.e. one with the filtered documents and the counts using [`$count`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/count/). The resulting streams can then
be aggregated further with a [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) as follows to get the desired result

```
db.getCollection('collection').aggregate([
    { '$facet': {
        'counts': [
            { '$match': { 'id': { '$in': ['111', '222', '333'] } } }, 
            { '$count': "numberOfMatches" }
        ],
        'docs': [
            { '$match': { 'id': { '$in': ['111', '222', '333'] } } }, 
        ]  
    } },
    {  '$project': {
        'result': {
            '$filter': {
                'input': '$docs',
                'cond': {
                    '$gt': [
                        { '$size': '$$this.tags' },
                        { '$arrayElemAt': ['$counts.numberOfMatches', 0] }
                    ]
                }
            }
        } 
    } }
])
```