# Feathers.js mongoose querying

Tags: feathersjs

I'm very new to feathers.js, how would you accomplish querying for an object?

```
{
   ...,
   obj: {
      foo: 1,
      bar: 1
   },
   ...
}
```

The following seems to not work

```
/some-doc?obj['foo']['$eq']=1
```

Also, how would you tackle a query like checking a size of array

```
/some-doc?someArray['length']['$gt']=0
```

I've been trying to send param like

```
checkArray=true
```

Process it at before:find but no luck. Is this the right approach?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, most queries supported by Mongoose and MongoDB will work for your Feathers service. MongoDB queries on nested fields [using the dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/#query-on-nested-field) so it would be:

```
/some-doc?obj.foo=1
```

Length queries can be done with the [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/size/) operator. To check if an array has a certain length, you can use the dot notation to see if the entry at the index exists (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15224544/120513)):

```
/some-doc?someArray.1[$exists]=true
```