# How to find using size array in couchdb

Tags: couchdb

How to create a query CouchDB to retrieve all documents where the size of elements is Greater than X.

This query return all documents `where movies.size  = 3`

```
{
 "selector": {
  "movies": { "$size": 3}
  }
}
```

I need to find `where movies.size > 3`

I'm using `CouchDB 2.1.1`

Comment: is it now possible in the latest version?

Answer (score 2):

This works for version 3.1.1.

```
{
   "selector": {
      "movies.4": {
         "$exists": true
      }
   }
}
```

*Trivial clarification: the 4 is because of you asked for > 3. If you need >= 3 use movies.3*

However, I don't think there is a way to index the elements of an array.

I kept the solution from a MongoDb answerer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15224544/846168

Answer (score 0):

This isn't supported at the moment in Mango. Altought, it shouldn't be hard to implement. At the moment, you can create a view that index the array lengths. From that, you could use `end_key=3` to get document with length lower then 3.

Answer (score 0):

if your list is not very long, consider using $or operator:

```
"$or": [
  {"movies": {"$size": 4}},
  {"movies": {"$size": 5}},
  {"movies": {"$size": 6}},

]
```