# mongo: query array field size is greather than

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Is there anyway to check documents which contains an array field with more than 0 elements?

I mean,

```
{
   "_id": "sdfsf",
   code: "code",
   array: ["any", "any2"]
}
```

I would like to get any documents where `document.array size is gt 0`.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811163/query-for-documents-where-array-size-is-greater-than-1

Comment: You can use $expr with mongodb 3.6 and above... Something like `db.collection.find({ $expr: { $gt: ["$array", 0]} })`