# Find where array size is equal to field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to find all documents where an array's size is equal to a field's value. For example:

This document should be found:

```
{
  arr: ["one", "two", "three"],
  expected: 3
}
```

But not this one:

```
{
  arr: ["one", "two", "three", "four"],
  expected: 2
}
```

I'm assuming I have to use some form of aggregation, so I've decided to use [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/):

```
$expr: { $eq: [{ $size: "$arr" }, { ??? }] }
```

Comment: This might be useful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811163/query-for-documents-where-array-size-is-greater-than-1

Comment: @MoA Unfortunately, it's not a predefined value, which is why I asked my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similarly as you used the `arr` field using `$` sign, you have to use for `expected` field

```
db.collection.find({ "$expr": { "$eq": [{ "$size": "$arr" }, "$expected"] })
```