# mongodb find. max count in array

Tags: mongodb, find

I'm use find in mongodb by array, but I don't know max count of array may be.

```
collection.find(test: {$in: [1,2...n]}).
```

No more than how many could be n ?
Please help me, if you sare links on documentation, it will best wonderful.

Comment: Check this link, it has the way to find the element by key: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811163/query-for-documents-where-array-size-is-greater-than-1

Comment: Thanks you, but its not what i need

Comment: Are you asking if there is a limit to the number of elements in the array passed to the `$in` operator?  If so, the answer is no, but sort of yes.  The entire query is a BSON document, and therefore cannot be larger than 16MB total, so you should be able to fit a pretty good array in there.

Comment: Thanks you, you can write it in answer