# Query for more than one text value in a field, MongoDB

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

For a document with fields:

`{"_id" : 1, "name": "Sarah", "fruitEaten" : ["apple", "banana", "orange"]}`

`{"_id" : 2, "name": "Steve", "fruit Eaten" : "apple"}`

`{"_id" : 3, "name": "Stacey", "fruitEaten" : ["apple", "orange"]}`

How can I query to get who ate more than one fruit eaten?

I have been trying `db.collection.find({"fruitEaten":{"$gt":1},{"name":1}})`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Query for documents where array size is greater than 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811163/query-for-documents-where-array-size-is-greater-than-1)

Comment: no unfortunately not, because I have realised all the fields aren't arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $and: [
          {
            $isArray: "$fruitEaten"
          },
          {
            $gt: [ { $size: "$fruitEaten" }, 1 ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jjsbDmFJAA5)

Comment: Thanks this is definitely helpful, I realised I was getting an error because not all the fields are arrays? And when trying "this.fruitEaten.length" those not in an array form I believe are counted by characters! Any suggestions?

Comment: @kedoink I update my answer.